# Replacing column values if they match one of two columns in another dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have example data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dat1 <- fread("code1 code2 code3
              A3     B2   C1
              A4     B3   C2")

dat2 <- fread("codes
              A3  
              A4
              B2
              B3")
```

I would simply like to replace the codes in `dat2` with `code3` from `dat1`.

Desired output:

```
dat_out <- fread("codes
              C1  
              C2
              C1
              C2")
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `match`:

```r
`%r%`<- function(x, y) replace(x %% y, x %% y == 0, y)
dat2[, codes := dat1$code3[match(dat2$codes, unlist(dat1)) %r% nrow(dat1)]]

#   codes
#1:    C1
#2:    C2
#3:    C1
#4:    C2
```

---

Explanation:

- This uses `match` on the `unlist`ed value of `dat1` (you can also only focus on selected columns).
- You can then use `%%` (modulo) to get the rest of the integer division by `nrow(dat1)`. Basically, it restitutes the size of the columns (relist).
- The problem is that it creates value of 0 where we need 2 (or `nrow`), hence the new operator.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `melt` along with join by `on = ...` if you are working with `data.table`, e.g,

```
dat2[
  melt(dat1, id.var = "code3"), 
  .(codes = code3),
  on = c(codes = "value")
]
```

which gives

```
> dat2[melt(dat1, id.var = "code3"), .(codes = code3), on = c(codes = "value")]
   codes
1:    C1
2:    C2
3:    C1
4:    C2
```

where `melt(dat1, id.var = "code3")` looks like

```
> melt(dat1, id.var = "code3")
   code3 variable value
1:    C1    code1    A3
2:    C2    code1    A4
3:    C1    code2    B2
4:    C2    code2    B3
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be one way to do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 %>% 
  inner_join(dat1 %>% pivot_longer(!code3), by = c('codes'='value')) %>%
  select(!name) %>%
  mutate(codes = coalesce(!!!rev(.))) %>%
  select(codes)

   codes
1:    C1
2:    C2
3:    C1
4:    C2
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with named vector

```
dat2[, codes := setNames(rep(dat1$code3, 2), unlist(dat1[, 1:2]))[codes]]
```

-output

```
> dat2
    codes
   <char>
1:     C1
2:     C2
3:     C1
4:     C2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on `match` function:

```
dat2[, codes := dat1[, rep(code3, 2)[match(codes, c(code1, code2))]]]

    codes
1:     C1
2:     C2
3:     C1
4:     C2
```